# Get 3 tables data in one query posgresql

Tags: postgresql

I have 3 tables in PostgreSQL.
the first table I have watertracker
1)tablename: watertracker

[image]

2)tablename:weighttracker

[image]

3. tablename: handwashtracker

[image]

I want to show below data in one query:
where cid is 86 and date is 2020-08-30 of all table data.

Comment: Could you show information about the relationship between tables? (primary key, foreign key)

Comment: Yes wt_cid, wet_cid,ht_cid is foregin key

Comment: Sample data is better presented as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking tables.

Answer (score 0):

To select data from all tables use `join` clause in the select statement as follows:

```
select * from watertracker wt
join weighttracker wet on wet.id=wt.cid
join handwashtracker ht on ht.id=wt.cid
where wt.cid=86 and wt.wt_date::date='2020-08-30';
```

Comment: getting issue ERROR: syntax error at or near "on"
  Position: 36